# MVC add list of items to the model in the create model view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a asp.net mvc website, and there is a model for an invoice
like this

```
namespace projectname.Models
{
    public class Invoice
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }


            public virtual List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and what i want is that in the create invoice view there should be a list from all available jobs with check-box's and the user should be able to check which job they want in the invoice.

**and when i get back the model i should get it with the checked jobs**

any idea how that can be done?

Comment: Please post the Job class and your controller

Comment: the job class is not needed because all i need is the id and a bool if it should be added,please look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

ok here is what i ended up using i'm still waiting to find a better way

i created a class (model)

```
public class addJob
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Add { get; set; }

}
```

then i made the action result like this

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddJobs(int? id, addJob[] addJobs)
```

and here is the view

```
<span class="uni">
<input type='checkbox' value='true' name="addJobs[@count].Add" class="addJobToInvoice-check" checked />
```

its on a for each loop and i get back what i needed